# dotPeek: "Type to search" field is missing

Tags: dotpeek

For as long as I can remember I had a search box near the top of the Assembly Explorer - this afternoon it's gone, and all attempts at restoring it have failed.

[image: dotPeek search missing]

Is this a bug or did I somehow closed it? Can I bring it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late answer.  You clicked the "Toggle auto-hide of search bar" beside the search box.  To get it back type any character when the focus is on the Assembly Explorer window.  The click the Pin to keep it visible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I did not find a way to simply bring back the search box.
Instead I reset all settings to default which made the search box appear again:
Go to Tools -> Options
On the bottom left click 'Manage…'
On the top right, click 'Reset All Settings'